# Find String in ArrayList Containing Phrase

Tags: java, string, search, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Strings and I want to find a String in that list containing another String.

Say if my list is:

```
{
apple fruit
carrot vegetable
cake dessert
}
```

I want to search this list for the phrase `apple` and get its index -- this would give me the index 0, in this case.

Is this possible?

EDIT: This is what I've tried, but not sure what to put in the if statement:

```
String msg = queue.get(0).getTitle();
            for(int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                if(messages.get(i)...) {
                    messages.remove(i);
                }
            }
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is possible and extremely simple. Please post what you tried so far and what isn't working and we can help you from there,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    String yourRequiredString = "dessert";
    data.add("apple fruit");
    data.add("carrot vegetable");
    data.add("cake dessert");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if (data.get(i).contains(yourRequiredString)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a hint :

Suppose your ArrayList is called 
`Stringlist`

```
String result = "result you desire";

for(String s Stringlist){
```

`if (s.equals(result)){
//do something 
} //end if
} //end for`

This will check the ArrayList elements and if it finds the string you searching for you can do something that is in your requirements

> Note : in your case the if condition should be like this `if(s.contains(result))`